# Destination ViewController not changing after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My destination ViewController has a number of labels and images which need to be changed dependent on the specific previous ViewController. I have a segue set up which should change these but for some reason it is not, even though the segue is being called.

My initial ViewController has a button which has a segue passing to the next ViewController with the name "aName". I'm probably missing something simple but I have been following another section of my code which does the exact same thing and works! I have also tested that the segue is successfully being called with a NSLog which returns fine. All the IBOutlets are also assigned correctly.

Initial View Controller.m:

```
#import "dViewController.h"

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"aName"]) {
            dViewController *dVC = (dViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            dVC.TitleLabel.text = @"abc";
            dVC.1Img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"somepath.jpg"];
            dVC.2Img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"somepath2.jpg"];
            [dVC.1Button setTitle:@"abcd" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [dVC.1Button setTitle:@"efgh" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
```

Destination ViewController:

dViewController.h

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *1Img;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *2Img;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *1Button;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *2Button;
```

Edit: From doing some more looking around I think I should be using a delegate. It seems quite complicated and not really sure where I start. But I'll have a go at looking at what's in this thread: [Changing label's text in another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193973/changing-labels-text-in-another-view-controller)

Comment: Have you checked dVC is not nil?

Comment: Are your view controllers in navigation controller? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to push to stack.

Comment: @Tander What do you mean by nill?

Comment: @sumofighter666 No, they are just normal view controllers.

Comment: I mean they should be definitely in navigation controller.

Comment: @sumofighter666 So for a segue to work, they need to be navigation controllers?

Comment: For what you are expecting to achieve yes. Unless you want to display your view as modal view. But this is not what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create a variable for each label you want to change  and in viewDidLoad assing the variable to the label.text

for example

```
 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"aName"]) {
        dViewController *dVC = (dViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        dVC.titleString = @"abc";
        dVC.1Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"somepath.jpg"];
        dVC.2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"somepath2.jpg"];
        dVC.1ButtonString=@"ButtonTitle";
        dVC.2ButtonString=@"ButtonTitle2";

    }
```

in DestinationController

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;    
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *1Img;      
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *2Img;      
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *1Button;  
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *2Button;  

    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *2ButtonString;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage*1Image;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage*2Image;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* titleString;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *1ButtonString;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)UIImageView *1Img;  
    @property(strong,nonatomic)UIImageView *1Img;  



 - (void)viewDidLoad{

   self.TitleLabel.text = self.titleString;

   self.1Img.image = self.1Image;

   self.2Img.image = self.2Image;

   [self.1Button setTitle:self.1ButtonString];

   [self.2Button setTitle:self.1ButtonString];

}
```

hope It help you, the problem is that with

```
 dViewController *dVC = (dViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

you only bring the controller not the view. and the IBOutlet belongs to the view and the view is not load  i hope you understand

Comment: That worked, exactly how I wanted. I'm not sure if everyone else understood what I meant. But this explanation makes sense to why it was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around segue.destinationViewController like this:

```
        dViewController *dVC = (dViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController);
```

Comment: yes just edited then, was meant to dVC-it's correct in xcode.

Comment: does it transition to the destination view controller?

Comment: no, @synthesize didn't change it, still not displaying.

Comment: if it's not transitioning, then no wonder label/image properties aren't being written. I'd check your initial and destination VC's in storyboard and make sure the segue name matches the specified identifier.

Comment: Sorry, meant it is transitioning, just not displaying the changed information.

Comment: you said that you checked with NSLog inside the if statement it matches identifier aName?

Comment: Yes I checked with the NSLog that it segue identifier is correct. Looking further into it, I think I might need to use a delegate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Read about app navigation principles. From apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html